# How to Add Event Listeners to SVG Elements Loaded From File Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, svg

#### Problem Statement

I'm trying to load an svg file dynamically, and then listen to click events on the individual svg elements. The svg loads fine, but I'm having trouble detecting /when/ it has loaded so that I can add the listeners.

#### Context

The svg is a map that will pop up when the user clicks on a field. They should then be able to select a country from the map. The svg needs to be loaded dynamically because the field can be parameterized with different maps.

### What I've tried

It seems like the common recommendation is to listen for a "load" event on the dynamically created element and then access the actual svg elements through the element.contentDocument property or the element.getSVGDocument() function.

```
var element = document.createElement('embed');
element.src = this.mapSrc_;
element.type = 'image/svg+xml';
document.body.appendChild(element );

element.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log(element.firstChild, element.contentDocument, element.getSVGDocument());
});
```

or:

```
var element = document.createElement('object');
element.setAttribute('data', this.mapSrc_);
element.setAttribute('type', 'image/svg+xml';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log(element.firstChild, element.contentDocument, element.getSVGDocument());
});
```

But in both cases I get a console log of:

```
null undefined null
```

What is the proper way to load an svg from a file and then add event listeners to it?

Thank you for taking the time to read this! I really appreciate any help :D

[EDIT: If you like you can view my actual code [here](https://github.com/BeksOmega/blockly/blob/demo/ProjectSummitFields/demos/.project-summit-fields/map/field_map.js#L74), but be warned it is pretty thoroughly tied to the [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/) framework.]

Comment: What is the value of `map`?

Comment: Sorry @AnuragSrivastava it's `element` is named `map` in my code, but I thought `element` would be more generic for the example. I guess I forgot to change it over in the console logs. Fixed!

Comment: Perhaps the data i.e. this.mapSrc_ isn't valid.

Comment: @RobertLongson I wish! But the svg is showing up correctly, the events just aren't working: https://imgur.com/a/U3skf7g

You can have a look at my sourcecode here: https://github.com/BeksOmega/blockly/blob/a58b6810d06127522ef4c0b2dc936108f5cfeae2/demos/.project-summit-fields/map/field_map.js#L74

But it's pretty well tied to the Blockly framework, so idk how helpful it will be.

Thank you for the suggestion! -Beka

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error it seems like this is a problem with running the page from file, specifically on Chrome and Firefox (works on Edge and IE11).

You can test this by downloading [this example page](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html). If you run it from file the icons stay orange, but the online page works.

I will continue with this by testing on Edge instead of Chrome, but other people may have different solutions for this problem.